# Winjs Navigate from PageControl doesn't fire ready event

Tags: javascript, windows, dom-events, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm learning to build a Windows 8.1 navigation app in Visual studio express 2013.

I've created a button inside home.html and bound a click event to perform the navigation to a `pageControl` element called `htmlcontrols` (the navigation works fine). Next I've created a new `pageControl` named `otherpage` and I've added another button but this time inside the `htmlcontrols`. I bound another click event to this button to navigate from `htmlcontrols` to other page.

The navigation flow should be:
home (click)-> htmlcontrols (click)-> otherpage

The second navigation doesn't work, I've tried to put a debugger inside the ready event on the otherpage.js but it doesn't fire.

htmlcontrols.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>htmlcontrols</title>

    <link href="htmlcontrols.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="htmlcontrols.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="htmlcontrols fragment">
        <header class="page-header" aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="back-button" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.BackButton"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">Welcome to htmlcontrols</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section class="page-section" aria-label="Main content" role="main">

            <button id="newButton">Link to another page!</button>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

htmlcontrols.js:

```
// For an introduction to the Page Control template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232511
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var nav = WinJS.Navigation;

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/htmlcontrols.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            // NEVER REACHES THIS POINT
            debugger;
            newButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      
                nav.navigate("/pages/otherpage/otherpage.html");
            }, false);
        },

        unload: function () {
            // TODO: Respond to navigations away from this page.

        },

        updateLayout: function (element) {
            /// <param name="element" domElement="true" />
 
            // TODO: Respond to changes in layout.
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
In htmlcontrols.js, the uri in the WinJS.UI.Pages.define() was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you found the answer. To be more specific, the location of the page's .html file in your project and the relative URI in WinJS.UI.Pages.define *must* match to correctly associate the code within the Page control and the HTML file. Otherwise what happens is that the HTML gets loaded just fine, but when WinJS looks for a defined page control it doesn't find a match and so it won't fire any of those events.

Note that if you give the wrong URI to Navigator.navigate and it can't find the file, that will throw an exception. But having the wrong UI in a Pages.define won't throw because WinJS assumes the page can run fine without event handlers.